# Which method does command 'rails generate migration CreateUsers' invoke?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am interested what method is invoked when I run the following command with some custom parameter. For example:

**rails generate migration CreateWord**

Sadly, I can't find it on Github repository as there are so many files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the [ActiveRecord::Generators::MigrationGenerator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator.rb) class?

Comment: This file seems to exist solely on Rails 5.

Comment: It goes back to Rails 3 as far as I can see. [Here's the one for Rails 4.2.6](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.6/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator.rb)